# How to print generated PDF automatically with Wicked PDF?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wicked-pdf

I'm using **Wicked** PDF and I generate a pdf in a new tab while clicking on the button. But I want to print the pdf by clicking the button **automatically**.I add this **print_media_type** and set the value **true** and I expect my printer options to start working but nothing happens! Have any ideas ?

```
respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.pdf do
          render pdf: "file_name", :template => 'officials/individual_receipt_export.html.erb', encoding: 'utf8',page_size: 'A4',:print_media_type => true
        end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, **print_media_type** option is used for styling your pdf file, not for printing it. 
To send pdf file directly to printer you can try following:

1. Generate pdf and save it to a file:

   ```
   # create a pdf
   pdf = render_to_string pdf: "some_file_name", template: "templates/pdf", encoding: "UTF-8"

   # then save to a file
   save_path = Rails.root.join('pdfs','filename.pdf')
   File.open(save_path, 'wb') do |file|
     file << pdf
   end
   ```
2. Call **lpr** command to print saved pdf file

   ```
   system("lpr", "pdfs/filename.pdf")
   ```

Comment: Works fine in Ubuntu Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in your controller:

```
def generate_pdf
  render pdf: 'sample_offer_letter', handlers: [:erb], formats: [:html]
end
```

And In Views folder, create file `generate_pdf.html.erb` as the following:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>PDF Title</title>
    <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "file.css" -%>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div>    
    <div>
      <%= wicked_pdf_image_tag @image %>
      <div>
        <h4><%= Date.today.strftime("%d %b, %Y") %></h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <h3><%= @variable_in_controller %></h3>
      </div>
      <br>
      <strong><%= @content %></strong>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Call this action, when you click on the button. That's working with me.
This action'll allow you to download PDF in your PC, Not open in new tab.

Comment: @Mohamad Yakout this solution didn't work for me.What's the difference between these two format of generating PDF ?

Comment: You server is WEBrick server, you run using `rails s` .. and your server stopped when you send request ? 
Are you facing this problem ?

Comment: @Mohamad Yakout I'm on rails five so I have Puma instead of WEBrick .no my server doesn't stop!